# How to remove undefiend path?

Tags: javascript, html

I want this...>C:\cutoff.docx...

But the result is showing like here...>C:\fakepath\cutoff.docx...

I want to remove \fakepath\ from this, how do I do it...?*

> HTML

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileupload"  style="display: none" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc, .docx,.ppt,  .pptx,.txt,.pdf"  onChange="Handlechange()"/>
```

> Script

```
<script>
function HandleBrowseClick()
{
var fileinput = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
fileinput.click();
}

function Handlechange()
{
var fileinput = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
var textinput = document.getElementById("filename");
textinput.value = fileinput.value;
}

</script>
```

Comment: if show fakepath, is because exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do `fileinput.value.replace('fakepath\\', '')`.

It's some browsers security action to prevent JS from knowing file actual location on computer.

This issue will not happen in back-end as there you will be using actual tmp path of file (that is already on your server when uploading).

Comment: You have an excess backslash.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov I may be wrong, but `\'` will escape `'` and will ruin code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the fakepath in the `[type="file"]` input. As i can see you want to show the path value in the text input now you can do as:

```
function Handlechange(){
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
    var textinput = document.getElementById("filename");
    var path = fileinput.value.replace('\fakepath','');
    textinput.value = path;

}
```

Comment: thanks @jai..Put it this way" fileinput.value.replace('fakepath\\', '')"